# How do I parse the fields in a comma separated list and convert them to Integer

Tags: c++, csv

I have the following:

```
char *strings = "1998,9,20,"
```

Here I want to store each number into an integer varaible and print as :

> 1998
>
> 9
>
> 20

I tried using `strtok` and then `atoi` but this did not help me as my variable is a character pointer and not an array.

Comment: Arrays decays to pointers to their first element, arrays and pointers can often be used interchangeably. And check out e.g. [this `atoi` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) and see what argument it actually takes.

Comment: I guess you try to pass the `strings` pointer as an argument to `strtok` which will segfault because string literals are stored in read-only memory but `strtok` expects the string to be modifyable. So you *have* to copy the string literal into an array before being able to use it with `strtok`.

Answer (score 0):

with `<regex>` library:
and `regex_token_iterator` as splitter:

```
unsigned int some_int[ 5 ]{};

const char* string = "1998,9,20,";

const char* begin_s = string;
const char* end___s = string + std::string( string ).size();

std::regex regex( "," );

std::regex_token_iterator< const char* > first( begin_s, end___s, regex, -1 ), last;

unsigned int index = 0;

while( first != last ){
    some_int[ index++ ] = std::stoi( *first++ );
}

for( unsigned int item : some_int ){
    std::cout << item << '\n';
}
```

the output:

```
1998
9
20
0
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does what you want to do in a simple way?

```
const char *strings = "1998,9,20,";
const char *ptr = strings;
while (true) {
    int val;
    val = atoi(ptr);
    ptr = strchr(ptr,',');

    if (ptr == 0)
        break;

    std::cout << val << std::endl;
    ptr++;
}
```